# How do I do do this UICollectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths Correctly in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In the most simple example, I can show that I've tried, I'm trying to remove items from `UICollectionView`, however I always get an inconsistency error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'

```
self.collectionView!.performBatchUpdates({
    self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths( [NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 1 ) ] )
}, completion: nil)
```

If you could show me a complete working example of a complete method that does this, it would be helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you in fact only have one section in your collection view? If so, you want NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection:0)

Answer (score 0):

Sections are numbered from zero. The error message is telling you that you tried to delete an item from section 1, but there is only one section in the collection view. Since there is only one section, that section is number 0.

Perhaps you want to do this:

```
self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem:0, inSection:0)])
```